# How to add third party plugins in my cordova plugin?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am developing a cordova plugin and I want to publish now. However, I need to invoke some third party plugins in my plugin, such as `cordova-plugin-camera` and `cordova-plugin-googlemaps`. Currently I'm merging everything and given source path in `plugin.xml` manually, which is a poor code management. I want to know if I can add the dependencies in `plugin.xml` and free my work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I'm helping my friends to solve his problem. Read this [Doc of plugin.xml](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html). And specifically:

> The `<dependency>` tag allows you to specify other plugins on which
>   the current plugin depends. The plugins are referenced by their unique
>   npm ids or by github url.

Therefore, what you should do is simple:

```
<dependency id="cordova-plugin-camera" version="^1.1.1" />
```

but be careful when you dealing with feature and permission in manifest.xml, if you still have those issues after addinig those dependencies, you need add them in `plugin.xml` as well:

```
<config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
    <feature name="Camera">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher"/>
    </feature>
</config-file>

<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</config-file>
```

Hopefully it will solve your problem.